# Открытие окон посредством сочетания клавиш

Tags: ubuntu, cmd, shell, скрипт, клавиатура

Возможно ли вызвать, непосредственно, сопричастно активированное окно, например cmd с отрытым cmus (музыкальный плеер), посредством некого сочетания клавиш.

Comment: Вроде можно на определенные окна задавать сочетания клавиш.В примере реализация питон-скрипта.
 ["шорткат" на окно](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49631/is-there-a-way-to-set-shortcut-keys-for-specific-opened-windows-in-gnome). Естественно конкретное решение зависит от используемой оконной среды.

Comment: "открыть" у вас это переключится на уже запущенное (в фокус и на передний план) или запустить новое?

Comment: " у нас это переключится на уже запущенное"

Comment: Попробуйте [`wmctrl -a 'cmus'`](https://superuser.com/q/142945/13868)